# Contar datos de un array sizeof()

Tags: c++

El tamaño varia pero si uso la función sizeof() siempre me arroja 8 así el tamaño sea mayor o menor o tengas mas o menos datos de 8, como puedo contar datos en c++ y por que sizeof() siempre lanza

Comment: Si quieres un array que guarda su tamaño, porque no usar las herramientas que ya te  ofrece c++? Tienes `std::array` y `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En C++ si tienes un arreglo, al usar `sizeof` obtendrás el tamaño total en bytes .

Para saber cuántos elementos tiene puedes hacer una simple división por el tamaño individual de los elementos:

```
int arreglo[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int bytes = sizeof(arreglo);
int elementos = bytes / sizeof(int);

// Normalmente int usa 4 bytes de memoria. Pero puede variar por sistema operativo o el compilador
// bytes = 20
// elementos = 5
```

Lo anterior también sirve para structs y clases.

---

El único caso en el que no podrás contar los elementos fácilmente es con punteros.

En un código como el siguiente (no tiene que ser memoria dinámica):

```
int* arreglo = new int[5];
```

`sizeof (int*)` no necesariamente es igual a `sizeof (int)`.

`sizeof(int*)` si es igual a `sieof(char*)` o cualquier puntero, incluso `sizeof(void*)`.

En sistemas de 64 bits, suele ser de 8 bytes. En sistemas de 32, 4 bytes.

Lo mejor sería guardar previamente la cantidad de elementos en una variable, y si quieres el tamaño total es tan simple como multiplicarlo por el tamaño de los elementos individualmente:

```
int n = 5;
int* arreglo = new int[n];
int bytes = sizeof(int) * n;
```

---

Si necesitas una estructura dinámica, puedes usar [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) para caracteres y [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) para cualquier tipo. Lo mejor es que no necesitas llevar la cuenta.

Aunque sí tendrás que recurrir al truco de recién para conocer el tamaño total:

```
std::vector<float> num;
num.push_back(1);
num.push_back(1.5f);
num.push_back(3.14f);

int n = num.size(); // cantidad de elementos
int total = n * sizeof(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

El operador `sizeof` te devuelve lo que ocupa un elemento en memoria. Esta descripción, así tal cual, parece muy chula, pero no es lo que estás esperando.

El operador `sizeof` se evalúa en tiempo de compilación, es decir, no va a ser capaz, en ningún caso, de hacer cálculos sobre la memoria dinámica. Entonces, ¿Qué hace exactamente este operador?

Como he dicho, te devuelve lo que ocupa un elemento en memoria, y así es:

```
int varInt;
std::cout << sizeof(varInt) << '\n';

int* varDouble;
std::cout << sizeof(varDouble) << '\n';
```

En este caso vemos como el operador nos devuelve exactamente el número de bytes de cada tipo de dato. También funciona con elementos más complejos como estructuras, clases y uniones:

```
struct s1
{
    int v1;
    double v2;
};

std::cout << sizeof(s1) << '\n';
```

El problema viene cuando usamos memoria dinámica. Aquí tenemos que tener cuidado ya que, como he comentado, el operador no va a tener en cuenta el consumo de memoria dinámica:

```
int* ptr1  = nullptr;
int* ptr2 = new int[100];

std::cout << sizeof(ptr1) << '\n'
          << sizeof(ptr2) << '\n';
```

Como ves, ahora el operador arroja el mismo resultado para ambos casos. Esto es así porque `sizeof` te está devolviendo el tamaño que se necesita para declarar un puntero. Este tamaño es independiente de la cantidad de memoria que direccione dicho puntero. Recordemos que un puntero es una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria, luego el valor devuelto por `sizeof` es justamente la cantidad de bytes que ocupan las direcciones de memoria.

Si manejas memoria dinámica necesitas llevar manualmente la cuenta de la cantidad de elementos que *entran* en dicha memoria:

```
class Vector
{
    int* data;
    size_t size;

    Vector(size_t num_elementos)
        : data(new int[num_elementos])
        , size(num_elementos)
    { }

    size_t Size() const
    { return size; }
        
};
```